# log into Facebook directly through a php script

Tags: php, html, facebook

I will save my username and password into the PHP script and it should log me into my Facebook account directly.
I tried to make it but got confused.
thanks.

Comment: **Unclear what you are asking**

Comment: And what did you try? Consider edit your question with what did you tried, 'cause this sounds like you expect someone to do your work. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I firstly saved the fb page then gave the value of email,and pass to my email and password

Comment: Then I used document.submit to submit the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not possible to do that, for very good reasons. You need to use an App and implement login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3

You can´t just store username and password and auto-login with a PHP script.

Comment: yes, there is a php sdk: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0